# how to use $watch for getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a iframe and when the source updated to the iframe, based on the loading time(some contains images so takes time to load) the width and height of the Iframe ie;`getBoundingClientRect()` changes. So each time i want to trigger the event, so how can I use trigger using `$watch`.

Comment: Please paste some code here and provide plunker link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Method:**

You can watch a function using $scope.$watch()

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div id="header">Example Header</div>
</div
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   let h = document.getElementById('header');

   $scope.$watch(function(){
      return h.getBoundingClientRect();
   }, function(newValue, oldValue){
      console.info("log", newValue, oldValue);
   });

});
```

**Second Method:**

MutationObserver: 
The MutationObserver interface provides the ability to watch for changes being made to the DOM tree.(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: thnk you Ankit Pandey :) it wrks fine

Comment: +1 For MutationObserver. $watch is not appropriate for reacting to DOM changes. $watch expression functions are only invoked during framework digest cycles. They are not reliable for reacting to DOM changes.